# .tex generated by Pandoc is incomplete

Tags: pandoc

I just started using Pandoc for converting my documents into several formats and it is simply awesome, especially when it comes to `.tex` to `.doc` conversion.

However, I'm having a problem with `.doc` to `.tex` conversion. The `.tex` file created by Pandoc is ... incomplete. It lacks basic commands like `\documentclass{}` and `\begin{document}`, `\end{document}`. Furthermore, the `.tex` file is filled with commands that seemingly depend on some other packages, like `\LR{}`. Such incompleteness makes my `.tex` file incompilable.

Is there any procedures that should be followed when one wants to compile `.tex` generated from Pandoc? Do I need to identify the missing commands and packages by inspection and add them myself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `pandoc -s ...` or `pandoc --standalone ...`.

This will tell Pandoc to create a standalone file which will include the preamble etc.